# MacOS using Rstudio running randomForest I get the error: "Error: protect(): protection stack overflow" and fixes aren't working

Tags: r, macos, stack-overflow, random-forest

This has been posted about before, I know, but I've gone through all of the potential solutions and with 64Gb of RAM, I should be fine. I've run far more RAM intensive processes, had this error, reset R_MAX_VSIZE, and been fine. This is its current setting:

```
> Sys.getenv('R_MAX_VSIZE')
[1] "300Gb"
```

Now I'm getting the error running the following script, and coercing the dataframe into a matrix has no effect:

```
> testdata2 = read.table("test4.csv", header=FALSE, sep=',', colClasses="character")
> colnames(testdata2) = c("species", as.character(c(1:(ncol(testdata2)-1))))

> test3_rf = randomForest(as.factor(species) ~ ., 
                        data = as.matrix(testdata2), 
                        importance = TRUE,
                        proximity = TRUE)
```

And here's some info on the dataset, which I don't consider to be particularly large:

```
> str(testdata2)
'data.frame':   46 obs. of  17000 variables:
 $ species: chr  "Enophrys bison" "Cottus beldingii" "Cottus beldingii" "Cottus beldingii" ...
 $ 1      : chr  "G" "G" "G" "G" ...
 $ 2      : chr  "T" "T" "T" "T" ...
 $ 3      : chr  "T" "T" "T" "T" ...
 $ 4      : chr  "G" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ 5      : chr  "G" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ 6      : chr  "C" "C" "C" "C" ...
 $ 7      : chr  "G" "G" "G" "G" ...
 $ 8      : chr  "T" "T" "T" "T" ...
 $ 9      : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ 10     : chr  "G" "G" "G" "G" ...
 $ 11     : chr  "C" "C" "C" "C" ...
 $ 12     : chr  "T" "T" "T" "T" ...
 $ 13     : chr  "T" "T" "T" "T" ...
 $ 14     : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ 15     : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ 16     : chr  "-" "C" "C" "C" ...
 $ 17     : chr  "-" "-" "-" "-" ...
 $ 18     : chr  "C" "T" "T" "T" ...
 $ 19     : chr  "T" "T" "A" "A" ...
 $ 20     : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ 21     : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ 22     : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ 23     : chr  "G" "G" "G" "G" ...
 $ 24     : chr  "C" "C" "C" "C" ...
 $ 25     : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ 26     : chr  "T" "T" "T" "T" ...
 $ 27     : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ 28     : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ 29     : chr  "C" "C" "C" "C" ...
 $ 30     : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ 31     : chr  "C" "C" "C" "C" ...
 $ 32     : chr  "T" "T" "T" "T" ...
 $ 33     : chr  "G" "G" "G" "G" ...
 $ 34     : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ 35     : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ 36     : chr  "G" "G" "G" "G" ...
 $ 37     : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ 38     : chr  "T" "T" "T" "T" ...
 $ 39     : chr  "G" "G" "G" "G" ...
 $ 40     : chr  "T" "T" "T" "T" ...
 $ 41     : chr  "T" "T" "T" "T" ...
 $ 42     : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ 43     : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ 44     : chr  "G" "G" "G" "G" ...
 $ 45     : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ 46     : chr  "T" "T" "T" "T" ...
 $ 47     : chr  "G" "G" "G" "G" ...
 $ 48     : chr  "G" "G" "G" "G" ...
 $ 49     : chr  "A" "T" "T" "T" ...
 $ 50     : chr  "C" "C" "C" "C" ...
 $ 51     : chr  "C" "C" "C" "C" ...
 $ 52     : chr  "C" "C" "C" "C" ...
 $ 53     : chr  "T" "T" "T" "T" ...
 $ 54     : chr  "-" "-" "-" "-" ...
 $ 55     : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ 56     : chr  "G" "G" "G" "G" ...
 $ 57     : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ 58     : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ 59     : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ 60     : chr  "G" "G" "G" "G" ...
 $ 61     : chr  "T" "T" "T" "T" ...
 $ 62     : chr  "C" "C" "C" "C" ...
 $ 63     : chr  "C" "C" "C" "C" ...
 $ 64     : chr  "C" "C" "C" "C" ...
 $ 65     : chr  "G" "G" "G" "G" ...
 $ 66     : chr  "C" "T" "T" "T" ...
 $ 67     : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ 68     : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ 69     : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ 70     : chr  "C" "C" "C" "C" ...
 $ 71     : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ 72     : chr  "C" "C" "C" "C" ...
 $ 73     : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ 74     : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ 75     : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ 76     : chr  "G" "G" "G" "G" ...
 $ 77     : chr  "G" "G" "G" "G" ...
 $ 78     : chr  "C" "C" "C" "C" ...
 $ 79     : chr  "T" "T" "T" "T" ...
 $ 80     : chr  "T" "T" "T" "T" ...
 $ 81     : chr  "G" "G" "G" "G" ...
 $ 82     : chr  "G" "G" "G" "G" ...
 $ 83     : chr  "T" "T" "T" "T" ...
 $ 84     : chr  "C" "C" "C" "C" ...
 $ 85     : chr  "C" "C" "C" "C" ...
 $ 86     : chr  "T" "T" "T" "T" ...
 $ 87     : chr  "G" "G" "G" "G" ...
 $ 88     : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ 89     : chr  "C" "C" "C" "C" ...
 $ 90     : chr  "T" "T" "T" "T" ...
 $ 91     : chr  "T" "T" "T" "T" ...
 $ 92     : chr  "T" "T" "T" "T" ...
 $ 93     : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ 94     : chr  "T" "T" "T" "T" ...
 $ 95     : chr  "T" "T" "T" "T" ...
 $ 96     : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ 97     : chr  "T" "T" "T" "T" ...
 $ 98     : chr  "C" "C" "C" "C" ...
  [list output truncated]
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. R shows only ~2.5Gb of RAM being used max.

Comment: In my experience the randomForest package doesn't cope well with datasets that are even slightly large. Have you tried implementing random forest via the `ranger` or `Rborist` packages instead?

Comment: i haven't! i'll give those a try. thank you!